# How to use SignalR hub instance outside of the hubpipleline

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I am using SignalR to broadcast messages to all my clients. I need to trigger the broadcasting outside of my hub class i.e. something like below:

`var broadcast = new chatHub();
 broadcast.Send("Admin","stop the chat");`

I am getting error message as:

> Using a Hub instance not created by the HubPipeline is unsupported.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You need to use `GetHubContext`:

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<chatHub>();
context.Clients.All.Send("Admin", "stop the chat");
```

This is described in more detail at http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub.

Comment: "context.Clients.All.Send" does not broadcast back to the caller, only to the others.   any ideas?

Comment: If you are using `GetHubContext` there is no caller as this is meant to be used outside of a Hub. `Clients.All` should address every client that is currently connected to the Hub.

Comment: Are you sure this works for self-hosted SignalR instances as well?

Comment: I have the same code, but the method Send or any other method would not be called .

Comment: This does not get you an instance of the hub, it gives you an instance of `IHubContext`. You can't use this to call hub methods.

Comment: This worked for me with ONE change: `context.Clients.All.broadcastMessage("Admin", "stop the chat");`  Use broadcastMessage instead of Send.

Answer (score 10):

A small update for those who might be wondering where the `GlobalHost` has gone. SignalR has been completely rewritten for .net core. So if you are using the SignalR.Core package ([Difference between SignalR versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-2.1)), you get an instance of SignalR hub context by injecting it into your service:

```
public class MyNeedyService
{
    private readonly IHubContext<MyHub> ctx;

    public MyNeedyService(IHubContext<MyHub> ctx)
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    public async Task MyMethod()
    {
        await this.ctx.All.SendAsync("clientCall");
    }
}
```

And in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddSignalR()/*.AddAzureSignalR("...")*/;
```

Microsoft docu is here: [Send SignalR messages from outside the hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: Thank you Maxim , this works perfectly for me `SignalR Core`.