# Call SignalR Client method from normal C# class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am trying to add **SignalR** in my MVC project. I need to call a SignalR client method from my class library. I did below code

```
public class CommomHubManager : ICommomHubManager
    {
        readonly IHubContext Context;
        public CommomHubManager()
        {
            Context = Helpers.Providers.HubContextProvider<Hubs.Notifications>.HubContext;
        }
        public Task AddUserToGroup(string groupName)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                Context.Clients.All.addUserToGroup(groupName);
            });
        }
    }
```

Its not working, but when i try to call an another Hub class method from WebApi its working just fine. I want to know that is it possible to call **SignalR** Client method from normal C# class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use SignalR hub instance outside of the hubpipleline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128125/how-to-use-signalr-hub-instance-outside-of-the-hubpipleline)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[How to use SignalR hub instance outside of the hubpipleline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128125/how-to-use-signalr-hub-instance-outside-of-the-hubpipleline)

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<CommomHubManager>();
context.Clients.All.Send("Admin", "stop the chat");
```

You can find out more in the [SignalR documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub).

Comment: i did the same but its not working for me. `Context.Clients.All.addUserToGroup(groupName)`;

Comment: resolved actually i was calling SignalR method before SignalR loads completely. Thanks