# Is it possible to use the signalr only for receiving data from server to Client?

Tags: c#, jquery, server, client, signalr

I  am Developing a Sample Application in SignalR. My Requirement is i need to receive datas from server to client.But i didn't any pass values from client to server.

**Is it possible to use the signalr only for receiving data from server to Client and i did correct?**

This is myHubClass:-

```
public  class NameHub : Hub
{
 public void send(string Item,string Info)
 {
  //var name = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NameHub>();
  Clients.All.broadcastMessage(Item,Info);
}
}
```

I need to use the HubClass outside the class.so i created a object for that hub class ,used in my solution.

**Sample:-**

```
using (NameHub n = new NameHub())
{
 n.Clients.All.broadcastMessage(datePicker, IsLoad);
}
```

**This is  my Owin StartupClass:-**

```
public class Startup
{
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
  {
    app.MapSignalR();
  }
}
```

MyClientSide Code:-

```
$(function () {
   var data = $.connection.NameHub;
   data.client.broadcastMessage = function (Item,Info) {
   $('div.container').append('<p><strong>'+Item+"=" 
           + Info + '</strong></p>');
};
```

Could Anyone Provide me an solution to solve this?

Please ensure i did correctly or wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To get Hub instance outside pipeline:
   [How to use SignalR hub instance outside of the hubpipleline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128125/how-to-use-signalr-hub-instance-outside-of-the-hubpipleline)
2. Don't forget start client side connection: `$.connection.hub.start()`