# Correctly lock a variable inside static method

Tags: c#, locking

I'm using SignalR to notify clients about some changes.
My hub (but it's not fundamental to know it's a SignalR hub) is defined as

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    private static readonly IHubContext HubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();

    private static readonly IDictionary<int, string> UserConnectionMapping = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    private const string UserId = "UserId";

    private readonly object userConnectionMappingLock = new object();



    public static void Static_UpdateStatus(int userId, string message)
    {
      lock(userConnectionMappingLock ) //This causes troubles
      {
         if (UserConnectionMapping.ContainsKey(userId))
        {
            var connectionId = UserConnectionMapping[userId];

            HubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).updateNotifications(message);
        }
     }
 }
 public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        if (Context.QueryString[UserId] == null) return base.OnConnected();

        var userId = int.Parse(Context.QueryString[UserId]);
        Log.Debug($"User {userId} connected on SignalR with Connection Id {Context.ConnectionId}");

        lock (userConnectionMappingLock)
        {
            UserConnectionMapping[userId] = Context.ConnectionId;
        }

        return base.OnConnected();
    }
```

Since it's static the method (and it can't be otherwise since I need to access from external classes), should I declare the lock static as well? Consider that there will be only 1 instance of NotifyHub. Thanks

Comment: You can't use a non-static member from a static method. The compiler will prevent you. Make it static.

Comment: That's not the correct way to do it, you should exctrat the ConnectionMapping outside the hub in a singleton expose Add and Remove methods to handle connected and disconnected users, and to access the bub oustide the hubpipeline, have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128125/how-to-use-signalr-hub-instance-outside-of-the-hubpipleline which points to this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub if it's not clear let me know I can give you sample code.

Comment: @lyz thanks for your point... an example would be really appreciated, why it's not the correct way to do? I don't either like the facto to have a static Hubcontext here

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're locking and the thing being protected should really have the same lifetime and scope; at the moment `UserConnectionMapping` is `static`, and `userConnectionMappingLock` is per-instance, which is a recipe for disaster.

Frankly, `static` dictionaries are always a little dangerous, but they **can** be used safely; options:

1. make `userConnectionMappingLock` match the scope of the dictionary - add `static` to `userConnectionMappingLock` (or remove `static` from `UserConnectionMapping`, see 3)
2. lose `userConnectionMappingLock` **completely** (just throw it away), and `lock` **on the dictionary itself** (`UserConnectionMapping`)
3. make `UserConnectionMapping` **not** be `static` - so you have a dictionary per hub instance (assuming the lifetime of `NotificationHub` works for that)
4. use `ConcurrentDictrionary<int,string>`

I'd probably lean towards the last one - you're less likely to shoot your foot off with it. Although I think a case could be made for applying 3 **in addition to** any of 1/2/4.