# Check overall progress of Azure Job and send it to an ASP.NET View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, signalr, jobs, signalr-hub

I'm creating a website with ASP.NET MVC5, hosted on Azure.
My users may upload a video, and I'd like to create a progress bar or something indicating how much % of the upload / transcoding has been done.

I'm following this [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-static-packaging) and the videos are correctly uploaded.
However, they show these lines of code once the job is sumbitted to Azure :

```
job = job.StartExecutionProgressTask(
  j =>
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Job state: {0}", j.State);
      Console.WriteLine("Job progress: {0:0.##}%", j.GetOverallProgress());
  },
  CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

I'm trying to adapt it to show it on my **webpage**.

## Question

However, I'm unable to "send" `j.GetOverallProgress()` to my view.
Can anyone explain how to do this ?

## What I did so far

Install Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR package (v 2.4.1)
(first time using SignalR)

Add these lines in my view :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/signalR/jquery.signalR-2.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var hub = $.connection.videoService;

        $("#btnCreate").on("click", function () {
            hub.client.displayProgress = function (data) {
                console.log(data); //Nothing is logged
            };
        })
    });
</script>
```

And these lines on my back-end : (VideoService.cs in \Services folder)

```
public class VideoService : Hub
{
    public EncodeMyVideo(...)
    {
        /* [...] */
        
        job = job.StartExecutionProgressTask(j => { 
            displayProgress(job); 
        }, CancellationToken.None).Result;
    }

    public double displayProgress(IJob job)
    {
        return job.GetOverallProgress();
    }
}
```

In debug mode, it goes to `displayProgress` method but never send anything to the view.

As a aside note, I also tried ith this :

```
public void displayProgress(IJob job)
{
    Clients.Caller.displayProgress(job.GetOverallProgress());
}
```

But I get this error :

> Using a Hub instance not created by the HubPipeline is unsupported.

I'm very new with SignalR, and despite [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128125/how-to-use-signalr-hub-instance-outside-of-the-hubpipleline), I don't really understand what the problem is.

What should I do to send `job.GetOverallProgress();` into my view ?

Answer (score 0):

displayProgress method runs in another thread so it does not share the same Context with the EncodeMyVideo method. So you need to use  GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<> to get your hub context and your client connections.

```
string callerId = Context.ConnectionId;
job = job.StartExecutionProgressTask(j => { 
            displayProgress(job, callerId); 
        }, CancellationToken.None).Result;

public void displayProgress(IJob job, string clientId)
{
  //Access to your hub context outside the request context
   GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<VideoService>().Clients.Client(clientId).displayProgress(job.GetOverallProgress());
}
```

For reporting progress you may also check this [Reporting progress from hub method invocations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#progress)